# Output Voltage Range of Op amps

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, cadence

I'm building a TIA circuit in Cadence as shown below. OP_LN is a module from AMS 0.35um Technology ([datasheet](https://ia601408.us.archive.org/25/items/op_ln_c35_revb/op_ln_c35_revb.pdf)). I think the configuration is correct.

[image]

And I'm expecting \$V_{\text{out}}\$ would be approximately 2.65 V because:

$$ V_{-} \approx V_{+}=1.65V $$

and

$$ V_{\text{out}} = V_{-} + I_{dc} \cdot R_{0} $$

However, \$V_{\text{out}}\$ is approximately -690 mV and \$ V_{-}\$ is -1.69 V according to the simulation. Obviously, that is because \$V_{+} \approx V_{-}\$ no longer stands(op amp failed to keep virtual short). Then I changed \$ I_{dc} \$ to 0.1 mA, and the behavior of \$ V_{\text{out}}\$ was as I expected.

I'm wondering if it is because \$ V_{\text{out}}\$ is out of the dynamic voltage range at the beginning, and where can I find this dynamic range in the datasheet. (Also, the dynamic range of 1 V does not seem to me to be very large.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Output source current is very limited:

[image]

And if you increase the resistor to \$10\text{ k}\Omega\$ and use a \$100\ \mu\text{A}\$ current source, you'd have to consider the high bias current: \$\approx 11\ \mu\text{A}\$

> where can I find this dynamic range in the data-sheet.

Within the current limits, they can be found at the end of table 4, relative to the voltage rails:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't know if I understand it correctly..So the current source draws too much current from the opamp causing the op-amp to operate improperly? And I'm wondering how is the bias current(11\$ \mu\$A) calculated.

Comment: The output of the opamp has limited current capability. If the current leaving the pin (source) or entering the pin (sink) is beyond the limits, you can consider that the component is being used outside the specs and other parameters (like output voltage range) can't be fulfilled. Regarding the additional question: the datasheet is very limited, so you could try to request more information from the manufacturer regarding the polarization current and how much current is demanded from the inputs.